# ubuntu 14.04 or ubuntuMate 14.04

Tags: 14.04, mate, ubuntu-mate

I am planning to switch from ubuntu 12.04 to ubuntu 14.04. However I am thinking to go for ubuntuMate 14.04 then ubuntu 14.04. 
I would like to know disadvantages of ubuntuMate 14.04 over ubuntu 14.04. 
According to ubuntuMate site, ubuntuMate is ubuntu + mate desktop. So is it true to say that whatever applications comes with ubuntu, they all would be present in ubuntuMate as well?. And if ubuntu releases any update, ubuntuMate would also get same updates on the same day?

Answer (score 1):

They use the same packages and repositories. The difference is in appearance and also some default applications may differ (Totem video player in Ubuntu vs VLC media player in MATE), but you may install or remove them after the system installation .
Also note that Ubuntu MATE 14.04 is not officially supported by Canonical yet.  Yet it is supported by Ubuntu MATE team.

So it is mainly matter of taste.(Also MATE is a bit lightweight than Unity)

Comment: UbuntuMATE is an official derivative now. It will never be supported by Canonical though. Only the primary Ubuntu images are supported by Canonical.